# Shuffle the order of a 2D array in java

Tags: java, arrays, shuffle

I'm creating my own memory game. Everything is going well so far. Just to let you know I'm using processing for Java. I have created a 2 dim PImage array. This is the code for filling the 2D array:

```
int g = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
 for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
  if (j % 2 == 0) {
    kaart[i][j] = loadImage( g + ".jpg" );
    kaart[i][j].resize(vlakGrootte - 1, vlakGrootte - 1);
    g++;
  } else if (j % 2 == 1) {
    kaart[i][j] = kaart[i][j-1];
  }
 }
}
```

I want the items in this array to be shuffled. It seems like java collections does not support to shuffle a 2D PImage array? Please correct me if im wrong.

Thanks to you all for helping me out.

Comment: With the right approach of Math.Random() you can do it, also with Collections.shuffle().

Comment: Yo can shuffle the indexes from 0 to 4x6 and then reorder your matrix based on the new indexes

Comment: Can you give me herhaps give me an exmaple? Well what i want to do is everytime i run the program that the images are shuffle. I tried it with Collections.shuffle(). But i can't get it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this the same way you would deal those cards in real world. First you shuffle the deck:

```
ArrayList<Integer> pieces = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4 * 6 / 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        pieces.add(i);
    }
}
Collections.shuffle(pieces);
```

Then you deal cards out of shuffled deck:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
 for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
    int g = pieces.remove(pieces.size()-1);
    kaart[i][j] = loadImage( g + ".jpg" );
    kaart[i][j].resize(vlakGrootte - 1, vlakGrootte - 1);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**1)**.Shuffle per-`outter` index :

```
 YourType [][] kaart = new YourType [..][..];

     List <YourType[]> list = (List<YourType[]> ) Arrays.asList(kaart);
     Collections.shuffle(list);
     kaart = (YourType[][]) list.toArray(new YourType[0][]);//convert back to a array 

     // just for checking 
     for(YourType[] k:kaart ){System.out.println(Arrays.toString(k));}
```

Replace `YourType` with the type of `kaart`.

**2)**. Shuffle per-`Outter+Inner` index :

```
YourType[][] kaart = new YourType[..][..];

     List<YourType[]> temp = new ArrayList<>();

     for(YourType[] k:kaart ){
         List <YourType> list = (List<YourType> ) Arrays.asList(k);
         Collections.shuffle(list);//shuffle  
         YourType[] tempArray = (YourType[]) list.toArray();
         temp.add(tempArray);

     }
     Collections.shuffle(temp);
     kaart= (YourType[][]) temp.toArray(new YourType[0][]);//convert back to a array 

         // just for checking 
     for(YourType[] k:kaart ){System.out.println(Arrays.toString(k)); }
```

Replace `YourType` with the type of `kaart`.

**3)**. Shuffle in `The easiest way`:

Just put all elements into a single `List` then call `Collections.shuffle()`

Comment: why are you using raw type?

Comment: well technically now the `[][]` and `[]` don't match :o

Comment: Hi! It is almost working. They get shuffled a "bit" it means that the duplicate of the card is always next to the original. This makes the game too easy. But we are almost there. Thank you for helping me so much!